# embed hyperlinks in a subliime text file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

One cool thing about Google Docs is that you can highlight a word, hit command-K (on a mac) and, hey presto, turn that word into a hyperlink.

One cool thing about Sublime Text is that it is better than Google Docs in every other way. My humble opinion.

Question: are there any plugins for ST that let you embed clickable hyperlinks into words? Specifically I want to do this for markdown files.

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are technically off-topic on StackOverflow. You might do better at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/). That being said, I did some googling and came across [this plugin](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/ClickableUrls_SublimeText). Haven't tried it, but it sounds like it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks mate, much obliged